# Unable to change boundary of the marker in Excel line chart

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have written the below code in VBA to make a line chart with dotted line style and also specific markers for only 1st and last data point. I do not want markers for all data points. In below code ch refers to the chart and variable i refers to series number

```
                With ch.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line
                    .transparency = 0
                    .Style = msoLineSingle
                    .dashStyle = msoLineRoundDot
                    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
                
                ' Set markers for the first and last data points
                With sC.Points(1)
                    .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
                    .MarkerSize = 5
                    .Format.Line.Visible = True
                    .Format.Line.weight = 1.25
                    If .MarkerStyle <> xlMarkerStyleNone Then
                        .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                    End If
                    .Format.Fill.Visible = False
                End With
                
                sC.Points(1).Select
                Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
                Selection.Format.Line.dashStyle = msoLineSolid
                                
                With sC.Points(lastPoint)
                    .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
                    .MarkerSize = 5
                    .Format.Line.Visible = True
                    .Format.Line.weight = 1.25
                    If .MarkerStyle <> xlMarkerStyleNone Then
                        .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                    End If
                    .Format.Fill.Visible = False
                End With

                sC.Points(lastPoint).Select
                Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
                Selection.Format.Line.dashStyle = msoLineSolid
```

but the above code is making the last portion of the line also as continuous instead of just making the markers with solid line. I managed to get the first marker correct though.

Any pointers on this would be helpful

Shown below is the image

[image]

Comment: What do you expect from this part: `sC.Points(lastPoint).Select` `Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue` `Selection.Format.Line.dashStyle = msoLineSolid`? I would suggest you to comment all this lines...

Comment: By doing that , I was trying to manually select the last point to make the boundary of the marker as solid line. When I comment that line the boundary of the marker also comes as dotted line.

Comment: OK, but is the line between the last node and the one before it, still continuous, after commenting these code lines?

Comment: After commenting , the line become as expected i.e. dotted but at the same time boundary of marker also becomes dotted. What I want is line to be dotted but marker boundary to be continuous.

Comment: Understood that... Please, insert the line `.Format.Line.dashStyle = msoLineSolid` after `.Format.Line.weight = 1.25` and let the above suggested code line commented. It looks that the point selection is extended on that line segment. In this way, it should strictly refer to the respective point and theoretically it should work as you need.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but still the same issue. It makes the last portion of the line continuous.

Comment: Can confirm that behaviour - looks to my like an Excel bug: Try to do this manually in Excel (not via macro): You get the same issue

Comment: If you do it manually by zooming and carefully selecting only the marker, you can do that. So manually it works, I have Excel 2019 with me.

Comment: I also played with manually changing the point border and **it is possible** to do it. In the manual changing pane there is a 'Marker' option, which I thought it should mean the point itself, having a `Border` property. VBA looks to not expose this property. `Point.Line` property looks to be common for the point itself, but **in the same time for the series segment before it**.

Comment: Sad, I was hoping for a way out. Anyways, thanks for trying.

Comment: Maybe look at this - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/differentiating-marker-line-and-series-line/505a39a9-3bd8-4c75-bf8a-edc8e6a01e12, where it's pointed out that the order you apply the formatting can affect the outcome.